# TikZ takes more than max LaTeX memory for complex R plot

Tags: r, plot, latex, tikz

I have a very complex plot, containing about 56,000 data points. It doesn't look right if I downsample it, so I really need to keep all of them. I would additionally like to add LaTeX captions to the figure. (The `expression` syntax, IMO, does not produce satisfactory rendering.)

After doing some digging around, TikZ seemed like the way to do it. But I found that it ran out of memory trying to plot the figure. I followed all of the advice I could find for TikZ memory management: this amounted to (1) using `externalize` and (2) increasing the `main_memory` for LaTeX to the maximum value (~12M). (I am using MacTeX 2014.) Neither of these solutions seemed to work.

At this point, having looked over SO and some other message boards, I am aware of only two options:

1. Switch to an alternate TeX interpreter, such as LuaTeX, which will allow me to use more memory, or
2. Use the native R plot, and then manually superimpose the desired labels onto the figures.

I consider (1) to be an acceptable solution, but the fact that I would need an alternate product makes me wonder if I am missing something. I wonder if there is a way to render complex native R plots, which happen to have TeX-style labels in them.

Comment: To use a modern-day cliche: You're doing it wrong.  There is no way that 56 000 data points are necessary to show anything, with the possible exception of the progression of a strange attractor algorithm.   Learn how to do density plots or clustering algorithms.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft for a tile plot, that's a resolution of 200x200, not unreasonable. I wish there was a way to tell the graphics engine to output some layers as raster data embedded in an otherwise vector plot.

Comment: @baptiste good point about rasterization.  Maybe there's a way to wedge that into the setup.  But using 56k data points to essentially paint a picture is certainly not the way to draw something :-) .